# Owin receive image upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

How do I declare in my **PUT** method parameters that I will receive a image in the body of the request?

Comment: I got it! use "Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();"

Comment: Consider posting your findings as an official answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! use "Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();"